# How to change system default assigned GID

Tags: linux

I created a new user named *test_user*. Here's the info:

```
test_user:x:1001:1001:Test User,,,:/home/test_user:/bin/bash
```

I then changed the *test_user* to *jwalker* by running the following:

```
sudo usermod -l jwalker test_user
```

Running the cat command, I get:

```
jwalker:x:1001:1001:Test User,,,:/home/test_user:/bin/bash
```

So far so good. I'm aware I have to change the UID and GID, but the problem is that when I change the GID, I still see the GID that was originally assigned by Linux when the user was created.

Change home directory:

```
sudo usermod -m -d /home/jwalker jwalker
jwalker:x:1001:1001:Test User,,,:/home/jwalker:/bin/bash
```

Change UID:

```
sudo usermod -u 1234 jwalker
jwalker:x:1234:1001:Test User,,,:/home/jwalker:/bin/bash
```

The question is, how do I change the 1001 GID assigned by Linux when the user was first created? When the user is first created, both UID and GID are the same. I want to have 1234:1234 for UID and GID respectively.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have not just the GID but a whole group named after the user (you can see it in /etc/group). Like with usermod, there is `groupmod` for editing groups:

```
groupmod -n jwalker test_user

groupmod -g 1234 jwalker
```

Comment: Thank you, it worked. Now, what's the difference between these two groups if you don't mind answering.

Comment: Which two? There's just one group.

Comment: I mean, the difference between options -n and -g

Comment: The first one renames the group (from 'test_user' to 'jwalker'), the second one changes its GID.